# obtain returned value in ILE cobol program

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

I am trying to get the returned value from a C program in a cobol program. However, they mention this:

[returning phrase](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statement-givingreturning-phrase)

"The GIVING/RETURNING phrase is not allowed for programs called with a linkage type of program."

So what is the alternative? how can I obtained the returned value in a cobol program? Cannot find it.
Thanks.
-- EDIT
I found this https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rdfi/9.6.0?topic=SSAE4W_9.6.0/com.ibm.etools.iseries.ilecbl.doc/LNC2762.htm
They indicate "change the linkage of the called program" but i don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer
ILE Programs on the IBM i don't support return values.
You'd need to use a output parameter.

Long Answer
In the JOBI0600 format of the [Retrieve Job Information (QUSRJOBI) API](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/qusrjobi.htm#HDRJOBI6) there's a 4byte integer field "User Return Code" at offset 108.

***However***
The documentation says:

> The user return code field is the most recent return code set by any
> thread within the job. Many operating system functions run C code and
> change the value of the user return code. Changes to this field occur
> at times that cannot be predicted or controlled by user programming,
> even when the job is single-threaded. To receive a value returned by a
> called program, it is better to provide a parameter to receive that
> value than to rely on this job-scoped user return code field.

IBM's Barbara Morris, part of the RPG compiler development team, [mentioned in an online thread](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00006LKocyCAD/receiving-return-codes-back-to-rpg-programs-after-a-call?language=en_US)

> the operating system has to take the program off the call stack, and
> if it's a *NEW program, the OS has to reclaim the activation group. If
> part of that work involves a C or C++ program in the OS, it might
> change the ILE return code.

**Expanded Answer**
"Changing Linkage" as mentioned in your edit would I suspect be moving the C code from a *PGM object into a *SRVPGM object (for bind-by-reference use) or *MODULE object (bind-by-copy).

ILE Procedures (aka Functions) can return values.

**For ILE C/C++ calling C/C++ PGM**
The following is mentioned in the [ILE C/C++ Programmer's Guide](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rdfi/9.6.0?topic=caipfic-passing-parameters-from-ile-different-high-level-language)..

> extern "OS" int PGMNAME(void); The value returned on the call is the
> return code for the dynamic program call. If the program being called
> is a C++ program, this return code can be accessed using the
> _LANGUAGE_RETURN_CODE macro defined in the header file <milib.h>. A C++ program returns four bytes in the _LANGUAGE_RETURN_CODE. If the
> program being called is an EPM or OPM program, this return code can be
> accessed using the iSeries Retrieve Job Attributes (RTVJOBA) command.

But I don't think that will help with COBOL calling C/C++.